# Android studio not working properly: code window not showing

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Unable to view the code window when I double click on the java classes or xml files, also the logcat and builds were showing empty.
How can I recover this issue?

Comment: is there any IDE internal errors? *bottom right of screen a red `!` mark*

Comment: yeah its showing like,
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Trying to override already registered file type 'Makefile' [Plugin: name.kropp.intellij.makefile]
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.loadFileTypeBeans(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:341)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.initStandardFileTypes(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:232)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.<init>(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:177)

Comment: I found these two solutions: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008165820-intellij-2020-1-stopped-working and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010628880-IntelliJ-Stuck-in-Welcome-Screen. also you can do your own research and maybe report it to google issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: also try resetting android studio or disabling plugins or creating a new project and check whether the problem still exists or not or in the end reinstall it.

Comment: I reset the default settings of the android studio and installed from start, and the issue get fixed, Thank you so much @MMD for the great support and sudden reply.